# Changing the format of the header

Tags: header-footer, templates

My \headmark looks as follow:

> Chapter Chapternumber. Chapter-title

How can I replace the . with a - ?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.5 (27/8/17)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[
english, % ngerman for German
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombat}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe it helps if you state your document class and the package for the header.

Comment: Thanks. I added the document class but I don't know what header I am using.

Comment: Then have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 and create a so-called MWE.

Comment: I also added a possible duplicate.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The question was closed as duplicate, the user couldn't get any help from the answers there. I vote to reopen.

Comment: Once reopened, i am going to add a CW answer and mark as duplicate.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/

Comment: By the way, questions about that template should be asked on LaTeX.org

Comment: @Johannes_B I also voted to reopen according to your request

Comment: @Johannes_B What is your connection to the template? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Dr.m i took over maintainership a while ago. https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md

Comment: And honestly, I would recommend *not* to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change `\chaptermarkformat`. See the package documentation of `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.5 (27/8/17)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[
english, % ngerman for German
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter\space}<-----
\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombat}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```